# Saving ipython variable/s to a text file

Tags: variables, text, save, text-files

I have a few lists and arrays in ipython which I should like to save to a text file so that I can then use them in another context. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the %store magic function

```
important = ['item', 42, 'list']
%store important

... time passes, sessions restarted

%store -r
%store
Stored variables and their in-db values:
important             -> ['test', 42, 'list']
```

Or, look to pickle.